# How to set the value in this mock object

Tags: java, mockito

How to set the value in mock object below.
I know how to get the value but how do set the value using mock?

```
    public class AUTest
    {

    Set<String> permissionIds = new HashSet<String>();

    @Mock 
    UserService userservice;

    @Mock
    PermissionService permissionservice;

    Set<String> emailid = new HashSet<String>();


    @Test
    public void getSuperUserPermissions()
    {
        List<Permissions> allPermissions = permissionservice.getAllPermissions();
        PermissionService permission = Mockito.mock(PermissionService.class);
        Mockito.when(permission.getPermissionById(5L)).thenReturn(pemission);
        Assert.assertNotNull(allPermissions);
    }

}
```

Comment: Which value do you want to set? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: want to set getPermissionById i want to set and get the parameters using mock object @lopisan

Comment: How does your PermissionService look like and what do you want to test? Sounds like you want to spy PermissionService instead of mocking it, but that is a little bit hard to tell without knowing any implementation details.

Answer (score 9):

Mock objects are used just to get values. You can setup what values are returned, just like jou did using:

```
Mockito.when(permission.getPermissionById(5L)).thenReturn(pemission);
```

Now when you call `permission.getPermissionById(5L)` you'll get `permission`.

Maybe you are talking about capturing parameters passed to the method. You can do it using [ArgumentCaptor](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html).

Sample code:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Person> argument = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Person.class);
verify(mock).doSomething(argument.capture());
assertEquals("John", argument.getValue().getName());
```